# Does double integral require reversal to solve?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm having difficulty solving the following double integral without reversing it. Is that the best approach? I have the sense that this problem is much simpler than I'm making it:

$${\large \int_{1}^{2}\int_{1}^{x^3}x\cos{y}dydx}$$

Without reversing the order of the integrals, I get:

$${\large \int_{1}^{2}[x\sin{x^3} - x\sin{1}]dx }$$

Better seems to be a reversal of integral order:

$${\large \int_{1}^{8}\int_{\sqrt[3]{y}}^{2}x\cos{y}dxdy}$$

Have I reversed the order correctly? And does the answer reduce to $\sin{8} - \sin{1}$ ?

Comment: Your reversing of order and limits is correct but how do you get that value for your integral? Reversal of order of integration does not make integral easier in this case unless you have written integrand wrong.

Comment: Reversing seems okay but this would not make the integral easier